# How do I write (not cite) Bible verses in MLA format?

Tags: citation, religion, mla

*For in-text MLA citations of the Bible, everything I've seen says to write the following:*

Saint John tells us that "God so loved the world that he sent his only-begotten Son" (*Revised Standard Version Catholic Edition,* Jn. 3.16).

*Apparently you use a period rather than a colon to separate chapter and verse. But what if I want to say the following:*

For the basis of his preaching Keble took Isaiah 49:23: in the Authorized Version, "And kings shall be thy nursing fathers, and queens thy nursing mothers" (Ellison 227).

*The Bible is not cited in-text because the verse was taken from an academic article. What about the* 49:23, *though? Does MLA allow for stylistic differences, or is a period necessary there as well?*

Comment: Whatever MLA says, it is very common indeed (see the Bible Hermeneutics Stack Exchange site, for example) to cite, or to write, biblical references with a colon - as in 'Mark 6:23'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, to quote @tchrist, questions about style guides are off-topic here.